# Exporting multiple arrays in a single HDF5 file in Mathematica 7

Tags: export, bugs, hdf5-format

**Bug introduced in 7.0 and fixed in 8.0**

---

I am using *Mathematica* 7 and I need to export a table of data and the corresponding `x` and `y` arrays. I would like to format them as a single file, say `grid.h5`, and need the arrays named for import in a different program. Unfortunately, applying the command:

```
Export["MGfunc.h5", {data, x1, y1}, {"Datasets", {"MGfunc", "x", "y"}}]
```

only seems to save the last array in the file `MGfunc.h5`.

Does anyone know how to get this working using the HDF5 format?

Here is an example:

```
ki = N[Table[i, {i, 0, 3}]] (* -> {0., 1., 2., 3.} *)
kj = N[Table[j, {j, 0, 3}]] (* -> {0., 1., 2., 3.} *)
testgrid = Table[ki*kj, {ki, 0, 3}, {kj, 0, 3}] 
(* -> {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 2, 3}, {0, 2, 4, 6}, {0, 3, 6, 9}} *)

Export["testgrid.h5", {testgrid, ki, kj}, {"Datasets", {"gridtest", "x", "y"}}] 
(* -> "testgrid.h5" *)

Import["testgrid.h5"] (* -> {"/y"} *)

Import["testgrid.h5", "Data"] (* -> {{0., 1., 2., 3.}} *)
```

Comment: Can you give a specific example of the values of the arrays data, x1, and y1? I tried the last example from the HDF5 documentation in Mathematica 9 and it seemed to work correctly exporting two matrices: Export["test.h5", {{{1, 2}, {2, 3}}, {{10, 11}, {12, 13}}}, {"Datasets", {"m1", "m2"}}]

Comment: I tried this example in Mathematica 7 also, and it didn't work. Here's another example:

In[13]:= ki = N[Table[i, {i, 0, 3}]]
kj = N[Table[j, {j, 0, 3}]]
testgrid = Table[ki*kj, {ki, 0, 3}, {kj, 0, 3}]

Out[13]= {0., 1., 2., 3.}

Out[14]= {0., 1., 2., 3.}

Out[15]= {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 2, 3}, {0, 2, 4, 6}, {0, 3, 6, 9}}

In[16]:= Export["testgrid.h5", {testgrid, ki, 
  kj}, {"Datasets", {"gridtest", "x", "y"}}]

Out[16]= "testgrid.h5"

In[19]:= Import["testgrid.h5"]

Out[19]= {"/y"}

In[20]:= Import["testgrid.h5", "Data"]

Out[20]= {{0., 1., 2., 3.}}

Comment: seems to be a bug in the export of version 7 only. It works for me with 6.0.2,8.0.4,9.0.1 on windows but not with 7.0.1. Import/Export seems to be done using an external executable connected with MathLink. Maybe one could try to exchange just that in version 7...

Comment: @Mr.Wizard are we removing (or no longer adding) version tags now for bugs that affect only a single version? I understand it is not useful for bugs that persist over several versions, but it could still be helpful for these version-specific bugs, just as a platform tag is useful for platform-specific bugs (and do we still add/keep those, or not?). I don't have strong preferences for either practice, but I just wonder about the pros and cons of each approach.

Comment: @Oleksandr By my interpretation of [this accepted proposal](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1364/121) we should not be applying any version tags to `bugs` questions.  For the sake of consistency I think this is best.  If you have a different perspective *please* post it in that Meta Q&A.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard okay. For consistency's sake it seems reasonable to apply this also in cases where only one tag would be required. I presume that means we are not using the platform tags any more either.

Comment: @Oleksandr As far as I know we *are* using platform tags.  There is usually only one of them, and we have not included that information in the standard bugs header.

Answer (score 3):

As [Albert Retey](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/169/albert-retey) notes in [a comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26991/exporting-multiple-arrays-in-a-single-hdf5-file-in-mathematica-7#comment84187_26991), this seems to be a bug specific to version 7 (or perhaps just 7.0.1), given that this behavior is not observed in versions 6.0.2, 8.0.4, 9.0.1 or 10.0.2.

Incidentally, you are absolutely right that the file is not exported correctly. If you use a different version to create it as it should be, version 7 will then be able to import it.